# Seed has_many relation using mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mass-assignment

Here are my two models:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :article
end
```

And I'm trying to seed the database in seed.rb using this code:

```
Article.create(
    [{
        content: "Hi! This is my first article!", 
        comments: [{content: "It sucks"}, {content: "Best article ever!"}]
    }], 
    without_protection: true)
```

However rake db:seed gives me the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
Comment(#28467560) expected, got Hash(#13868840)

Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It is possible to seed the database like this?

If yes a follow-up question: I've searched some and it seems that to do this kind of (nested?) mass assignment I need to add 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' for the attributes I want to assign. (Possibly something like 'accepts_nested_attributes_for :article' for the Comment model)

Is there a way to allow this similar to the 'without_protection: true'? Because I only want to accept this kind of mass assignment when seeding the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this error is that when you assign an associated model to another model (as in @article.comment = comment), it is expected that the right hand side be an actual object, not a hash of the object attributes.

If you want to create an article by passing in parameters for a comment, you need to include
`accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments` in the article model and add `:comments_attributes` to the `attr_accesible` list.

This should allow for what you've written above.

I don't believe it is possible to have conditional mass-assignment as this might compromise security (from a design standpoint).

EDIT: You also need to change comments: `[{content: "It sucks"}, {content: "Best article ever!"}]` to `comments_attributes: [{content: "It sucks"}, {content: "Best article ever!"}]`

Comment: Thanks, it works. The only problem now is that "without_protection: true" is no longer needed. I don't really like exposing more of the model than necessary just to make it more convenient to seed the database :/

Comment: The only new attribute you're exposing here is :comment_attributes, and since these are just forwarded to the Comment model (where the only accessible attribute is :content), you're not actually exposing any more of the models than before.

Comment: In other words, :comments_attributes is not really part of the model, rather it is a hash of model attributes (which happen to be accessible anyway).

Comment: @cdesrosiers How can i buy you a beer for this answer ?? I have been going around of this for hours now. Thank you !!!